# How to import dataset of images into auto-keras program

Tags: python, image, keras, deep-learning, auto-keras

I'm trying to use auto keras to create a model that can identify between pictures of two different skin diseases. I'm having an issue with how to import my dataset into the code.

I've based my code off of the sample code from the auto keras documentation for the mnist dataset.

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from autokeras.classifier import ImageClassifier

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape + (1,))
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape + (1,))

    clf = ImageClassifier(verbose=True, augment=False)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train, time_limit=12 * 60 * 60)
    clf.final_fit(x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, retrain=True)
    y = clf.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    print(y * 100)
```

I expect the output to give me similar results in my terminal as when I run the mnist sample code.